# If cells contains a certain texts then put a specified texts in other cells

Tags: excel

In **Sheet1** I have a big chuck of different links, looks something like this:

```
A,B
http://www.shop.com/suppliers.html   
http://www.forum.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=6283&start=
http://www.wikipedia.org
http://www.website.com
```

I want to define fast what kind of websites this is, for example:

- In A1 the URL contains "suppliers", I want to B1 to be "Suppliers"
- In A2 the URL contains "viewtopic", I want to B2 to be "Forum"
- In A3 the URL contains "wiki", I want to B3 to be "Information"
- In A4 the URL dosen't contains anything usefull (not defined in Sheet2), I want to B4 to be "Not
  found"

There are thousands of these "rules" for all URL's and the list will continuously grow.

Therefore the best solution would be to have all the "rules" in **Sheet2**. Where A-column correspond to `*contains*` and B-column correspond to the desired output.

```
A           B
suppliers   Suppliers
providers   Suppliers
/forum/     Forum
viewtopic   Forum
Trad.aspx   Forum
wiki        Information
```

So, in the end I want **Sheet1** to lool like this:

```
A                                                         B
http://www.shop.com/suppliers.html                        Suppliers
http://www.forum.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=6283&start=   Forum
http://www.wikipedia.org                                  Information
http://www.website.com                                    Not found
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a table with your equivalencies; named the table `Types`, and entered column headers of `contains` and `output`

[image: Types Table]

You can then use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Types[Contains],A1)),Types[Output]),"Not Found")
```

[image]

IF you choose not to use the table, you can replace the table references with absolute range references

```
eg:  Types[Contains]:=  Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6
```

However, an advantage of the Table structure, in your situation, would be that the structured reference would automatically expand as you added equivalencies.

Comment: A table seems convenient, this works excellent.

Note: I had to change the formula to `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2;1/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Types[contains];A14));Types[output]);"Not Found")` for it to work.

Comment: @Liu Kang. That is because my country has different separators than yours.

Answer (score 1):

In the following example, I have put the lookup table and the values on a single worksheet for demonstration purposes.

[image: Index Lookup]

The formula in B2 is,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($AB$2:$AB$99, MIN(INDEX(ROW($1:$98)+(ISERROR(SEARCH(AA$2:AA$99, A2))+NOT(LEN(AA$2:AA$99)))*1E+99, , ))), "")
```

Fill down as necessary. When transcribing for your own purposes, remember that all of the ranges have the same number of rows although they do not have to be the same rows. AA2:A99, AB2:AB99 and Row(1:98) all have 98 rows.